# Embedding hundreds, even thousands of pdf files in excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

Would it be possible and efficient to insert - object about 1000 PDF files to an excel document, or will it start running extremely slow/other problems?

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve exactly?

Comment: I have some 1000 PDF filed on a network drive and I've linked them to my excel document but for some reason, excel keeps changing the path. See: http://superuser.com/questions/783347/hyperlinks-to-documents-have-changed

So I'm trying to find other solutions.

What would be the best way to link 1000 PDF files to an excel document so that you can click a link in excel to open a file?

Answer (score 0):

I can't think of a reason that excel should change the file path.  If you want a way to update hyperlinks faster you could use something like this.

You specify a file directory and it assumes all the values in column A are the pdf names (without .pdf at the end) and it adds all the hyperlinks.

```
Sub add_hypers()

Dim last As Integer
Dim x As Integer
Dim name As String
Dim directory As String
Dim file As String

directory = "C:\"

last = Data.Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row

For x = last To 2 Step -1
    name = Data.Range("A" & x).Value
    file = directory & name & ".pdf"
    ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Data.Range("A" & x), Address:=file
Next


End Sub
```